# Is PCA considered as a data pre-processing algorithm or a standalone clustering algorithm?

Tags: cluster-computing, k-means, pca, decomposition

For many times I am told that PCA is a data preprocessing procedure; we could represent the characteristics of sample data by using principal components. Some times, however, I see a clear clustering trend if we plot the sample with PC1 and PC2. So is it ok to consider PCA a standalone clustering algorithm? or should we always apply another clustering algorithm, such as K-mean, after PCA?